# A Stars and Bars for powers of 2

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I was wondering if there is a closed expression for how many ways you can express a power of 2 as sum of $k$ powers of 2. That is, given $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ is there an explicit formula for
$$
\#\{(l_1, \dots, l_k) \in \mathbb{N}^k:\sum_{i=1}^k =2^n \text{ and }\forall i=1, \dots, k, \exists j_i \in \mathbb{N}, l_i = 2^{j_i} \} ?
$$

Where $\#$ denotes cardinality of a set.

Comment: In your equation statement, did you mean to add that $$\sum_{i=1}^k 2^{l_i} = 2^k$$

Comment: Would that just be the partitions of the power of $2$?

Comment: Yes, i will fix it now.

Comment: @Mark Fischler Actually, I meant this new statment,  not necessarily with the number of parcels on the sum being the power of 2.

Comment: @hypergeometric no because for example 4 admits the partition 1+3, and 3 is not a power of 2.

Comment: OK - it would be the partition if the question had been about *products* of power of $2$.

Comment: Just to check if I understood correctly: you want $k$ powers of two that sum up to another power of two. Are permutations, like, say, $16=8+4+2+1+1=1+2+1+8+4$ to be distinguished or counted as one?

Comment: I would like to count permutations as different.

Comment: Let $T(n,k)$ be the number of compositions $2^n$ into $k$ powers of $2$. [OEIS A323840](https://oeis.org/A323840) is the triangle of numbers $T(n,k)$ read by rows as a single sequence. The OEIS entry has neither a closed formula nor a recurrence for these values, so it’s fairly likely that none is known.